# Determine users and roles for all databases without sysadmin rights

Tags: sql-server, user-roles

We are creating a tool that maps all logins, users and roles for each database of all of our SQL servers. We want to do this periodically and compare results to give insight into changes.

Initially we started with `exec sp_MSloginmappings`, however we need a user with the sysadmin role for that.

Then we queried `sys.database_principles`. But we could only see our own user unless we granted the `ALTER ANY USER` and `ALTER ANY ROLE` permissions.

> Any user can see their own user name, the system users, and the fixed database roles. To see other users, requires ALTER ANY USER, or a permission on the user. To see user-defined roles, requires ALTER ANY ROLE, or membership in the role.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql

We consider the `ALTER ANY USER / ROLE` permissions to be too broad for our use-case.

That last option we considered was to create a stored procedure that queries that `sys.database_principles` as `dbo` by using `WITH EXECUTE AS`. This works but requires the stored procedure to be present in each database. Considering the use-case this is not ideal either.

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Thanks everybody!!